# Security risks using jqwidget

Tags: php, jquery, json, security, jqwidget

Are there any security risks using the jqwidget way of data loading from remote database i.e giving the path of the php file that just echoes the  json data?

Here is a sample code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [
            { name: 'CompanyName'},
            { name: 'ContactName'},
            { name: 'ContactTitle'},
            { name: 'Address'},
            { name: 'City'}
        ],
        url: 'grid_data.php',
        cache: false
    };
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
    {
    source: source,

    columns: [
        { text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 250},
        { text: 'ContactName', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
        { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'ContactTitle', width: 180 },
        { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 200 },
        { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 120 }
    ]
    });        
});
```

Comment: Every remote interaction poses a security risk. Your server operates most safely when shut-down and taken off the grid. So you perhaps provide some context about which kind of security you ask here? Or it's perhaps you ask out of the blue like a security risk nobody noticed so far but thanks to your question a review has started?

Comment: For example, the         url: 'grid_data.php' line here provides a name of a php file that I might not want to show, or a risk to show the design of the database.

Also i wanted to ask if using https is more secure?

Comment: To show the name of the PHP file is not insecure on it's own, it actually is necessary otherwise the script couldn't request data from it. Using HTTPS secures the transportation of the data, not the php script itself. You should search for the more concrete questions directly, you'll get much more background information then.